# Browserify order of files

Tags: browserify

I'm reading **Full Stack Web Development with Backbone.js** by Patrick Mulder, he introduces the use of browserify.

He explains that we must code a js file /app/main.js, and then browserify it into static/bundle.js, I had no problems bundling it. But I have found some problems following the book examples, and the first thing I did to debug was to compare [the author working bundle.js](http://pipefishbook.com/ch_4/routes/bundle.js) agains mine. Well, even when the bundled main.js and other js are the same, the bundle.js aren't equal. So I guess this is the start point of my problems.

My node version is: v0.10.33, my browserify version is: 8.0.1

As the book says, this is the command I use to generate bundle.js from main.js:

```
browserify -r ./app/main.js:app > static/bundle.js
```

To start off some differences:

1. The author main.js is placed on top of bundle.js
2. My main.js is placed on bottom of bundle.js
3. The first line of author's bundle.js starts with `(function e(t,n,r)....`
4. My first line starts with `require=(function e(t,n,r)....`

[main.js source code link](https://github.com/pipefishbook/ch_4/blob/master/layout/app/main.js)  from git repository. It is exact as I have.

The code from main.js is:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var $ = require('jquery-untouched');
Backbone.$ = $;
var MoviesRouter = require('routers/movies');
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('init');
  var router = new MoviesRouter({el: $('#movies') });
  Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true,
    root: '/'
  });
});
```

That code is exact the same I'm using, as the book says.
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yy3v7o5z/7/) where I pasted the code from my bundle.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the actual problem you're experiencing? Don't worry about the details of what's in the bundle unless it's not performing the way it should. How are #1 and #2 affecting your use of the bundle?

#3 and #4 are explained by your use of the `-r` (`--require`) flag. If you do this, your bundle won't start with `require=...`:

```
browserify ./app/main.js -o static/bundle.js
```

Are you trying to expose `./app/main.js` externally?

Comment: I have cloned repository and it executes automatically: https://github.com/pipefishbook/ch_4/tree/master/layout. Then to test I have deleted author bundle.js that worked and browserify it, then it doesn't auto executes even with repository files.

Comment: Your answer seems to fix the problem, I'll mark as correct, thanks for your help. So I can not do both expose externally and auto run it right?

Comment: @RicardoCastañeda Ah, I see. You're welcome. I don't have a good answer for your question. The semantics of things like requiring files and exposing modules externally with browserify are poorly documented (and possibly unstable / buggy) and I'm trying to understand them better myself, e.g.: [Controlling exposure of bundled modules #1039](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1039). I suggest you upgrade to the latest version of browserify and try pointing to `main.js` as an entry file *and* a required file and see if that works. I also just found issue #1020 -- perhaps related.